# SQL query for all grouped records in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's consider a toy example. There is a table employees and table tasks, where each task is assigned to one employee. One employee can have multiple tasks.

I want to query employees filtering them by some columns in their tasks. I group the employees to display each one only once. The query would be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees emp JOIN tasks tsk on emp.id = tsk.assigned_emp
WHERE tsk.deadline = today
GROUP BY employees
```

This works fine, but now let's say that I'd like to select the employees that don't have **any** tasks which deadline is due today. My first try was:

```
tsk.deadline != today
```

but then is finds employees with at least one task that is not due today. How to write a query to include **all** possible tasks for a given employee?

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern for this.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM employees emp 
  LEFT JOIN tasks tsk   ON emp.id = tsk.assigned_emp
                       AND tsk.deadline = today
 WHERE tsk.deadline IS NULL
 GROUP BY employees
```

`JOIN` removes rows from its first table that don't match your ON condition. By contrast, `LEFT JOIN` leaves them in place putting NULL values into the result columns from the second table.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different solutions for this antijoin task. One of them is using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM tasks t
  WHERE e.id = t.assigned_emp and t.deadline = today
)
```